# Duvida referente a informar versão no Bower

Tags: front-end, bower

Bom dia pessoal!

Estou desenvolvendo um site simples com o objetivo de estudo de front end e me deparei com uma dúvida referente ao Bower, ferramenta que estou utilizando para gerenciar as dependências, a qual não consegui sanar devidamente lendo a documentação do mesmo.

Tenho o seguinte bower.json:

```
{
   "name": "my-project",
   "dependencies": {
      "highcharts": "-3.0.10",
      "jquery": "^1.20"
   }
}
```

Minha dúvida é em relação aos símbolos **'-'** e **'^'** que vem antes do número da versão.
Lendo a documentação ainda não ficou muito claro para mim.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Cara o seguinte: o `^` significa que o Bower poderá atualizar pacotes somente para versões que alteram a terceira posição da versão (ou seja, atualizações de correção que mantenham a compatibilidade, correções de bugs, etc...).

> Já para este sufixo **'-'**, não achei em documentação nenhuma referenciando este sinal para versionamento com **Bower**.

Se quiser saber mais sobre versionamento [leia aqui](https://semver.org/lang/pt-BR/).

Se quiser saber o que cada sufixo faz no `Bower` [leia aqui](https://github.com/deppbrazil/bower).